# How to use javascript methd from external files in hbs file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Let's say i have a simple project, index.html and one .js file with a method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<HEAD>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Project</title>
</HEAD>
<body>
<textarea id ="someID" name = "textFieldName"></textarea>
<button onclick="showNewData()">Button</button>
<p id="score"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function getText(){
  value = document.getElementById('someID').value;
}
 
function showNewData(){
  getText();
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = "Current data: "+value;
}
```

I tried to do the same on localhost:3000. So i've done npm project with express and hbs dependencies.  It start from server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const port = 3000;
 
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
 
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
})
 
app.listen(port);
```

In "views" folder i have hbs file looked the same like former index.html file but it can't use javascript method from external file. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in hbs file

As far as the browser knows, it is HTML. Clients do not care, and cannot know, if an HTTP response is generated by reading a static file or dynamically with some form of server side processing.

> ```
> src="controller.js"
> ```

The value of the `src` attribute has to resolve to a URL containing the JavaScript

> ```
> app.get('/', (req, res) => {
>     res.render('index')
> })
> ```

The only URL your web server knows about (and so will provide anything other than a 404 error for) is `/`.

If you want `/controller.js` to provide a JS file then you need to write code to make that happen.

How to handle [static files is covered in the Express Getting Started Guide](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).